# Error on socket disconect

Tags: java, sockets

I made a program to keep connected to a server. It has many packets always from recv and send, never disconnects (like a game). It works perfect all the time, but when the **server lost the connection** with the client, one of the following happens:

1. `channel.read` returns -1. It disconnects with no error.
2. `channel.write` throws an exception. It calls to `closeServer()`, `channel.read` return -1 and disconnect with no problem.
3. `channel.read` **never returns**. `channel.write` is called too many times, it always throws an exception, but the `channel.read` never returns.
4. `channel.read` never returns. `channel.write` never throw an exception. After a while, `channel.write` never returns. It gets stacked with no errors. Sometimes it never get stacked, it always write the bytes, but the connection is over.
5. `channel.read` never returns, `channel.write` never throws an exception. I call `closeServer()` by hand, but it gets stacked, the `channel.close();` never returns.

I'm getting crazy with this. This is the source code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;

public class Client {
    Boolean close = false;
    SocketChannel channel = null;
    JFrame window;

    public Client(JFrame window){
        this.window = window;
    }
    public void send (String s){
        try {
            channel.write(StringToByteBuffer(s));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            window.error("Error writing data\n");
            closeServer();
        }
    }

    public void Connect (){

        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(1024);
        InetSocketAddress socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress("xx.xx.xx.xx", 800);
        try {
            channel = SocketChannel.open();
            channel.connect(socketAddress);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            window.error("Unable to connect to server\n");
        }

        send("Login String");

        try {
            while ((channel.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                buffer.flip();
                proccessBuffer(buffer);
                buffer.clear();
                if (close){
                    channel.close();
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            window.error("Error reading data\n");
            closeServer();
        }
        window.setServerOffline();
    }

    public void closeServer(){
        try {
            channel.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            window.error("Error closeing socket");
        }
        close = true;
    }
}
```

I created a thread to this class from the main JFrame, like:

```
new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                client = new Client(window);
                client.Connect();


            }}.start();
```

`window` is a JFrame and `client` is the Client class.

Comment: how can i detect and close the socket on the 3), 4) and 5)

Comment: Not sure if this is the case here, but is it possible that you are getting a null? Try and checking for a null on read from server and see what happens.

Comment: You are making a *major* error by not printing the actual exception message. As a result you have no idea what the errors actually are, and therefore neither do we. Fix your code to print the actual error, not something you've made up, rerun, and report the actual error(s) here. Until you do that you're not likely to find anything out at all, either by yourself or by assistance here.

Comment: the major problem is that read never return null or -1. No error throw. And sometimes, write function never throws a exception, just seems to write all the bytes (and sometimes, the function frozen and never returns.)